# Change Permission of a Single Folder - Windows

Tags: windows, permissions

I have a folder containing many other folders for each day of year each of which contains a large number of images.
Due to some sort of inconveniences the permission of this folder alone is changed not its children. I want to give this **'Authenticated Users'** permission to modify this folder. By doing so windows will change the permission of all the sub-folders and files in this directory. which takes so much time...

I even select the **'This Folder Only'** in the **Applies to** option; but that does not work for me.

Is there any way to change the permission of this folder alone and not its children?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to be annoying the first time around, but you have to go to each of the child folders (just the first layer down if you have folders inside folders) and turn off inheritance from parent. Once that's done, you can mess with the parent folder independently.